# How to transition full page using CSS3 and support IE8, IE9?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I'm working on a Q and A quiz game, where I should show only one question per page (full page). Each page has 2 buttons **YES** and **NO**.

Without scrolling, when a user click on **NO** the full page transit left and show the correct answer. When user click **YES** the full page transit down for next question.

I have checked the [FullPageJs](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage) JS libraries such as, but I want to do it without any library.

I have tried transition full page from top to bottom only, but wasn't able to do transition form left to right.
How could I go about such transition for full page and support IE8 & IE9?
Thanks!

**Html:**

```
    <body>
    <div class="site-wrapper">
        <div class="site-wrapper-inner">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="brand-image-container">
                        <div class="centerer"></div>
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x70" alt="" /> 
                    </div>                      
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="img-container">
                        <div class="centerer"></div>
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/400x250" alt="" />    
                    </div>

                <div class="wrapper">
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus amet optio vel alias nobis nostrum quaerat quas doloremque, libero dicta pariatur cupiditate, reiciendis quo nihil dolorem. Tempora saepe suscipit consequatur!
                    </p>                    
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>

        <div class="footer">
            <a href="#" class="button btn-medium btn-true">TRUE</a>
            <a href="#" class="button btn-medium btn-false">FALSE</a>
        </div>              
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box; }

html {
  font-family: "Lucida Sans", sans-serif, Arial;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; }

body {
  margin: 0; }

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, main, nav, section, summary {
  display: block; }

p {
  margin: 0; }

.site-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: #CBD7F5;
  overflow: hidden; }

.site-wrapper-inner {
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #aaa;
  overflow: hidden; }

.container {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left; }

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 10px; }

.img-container, .brand-image-container {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 10px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  /* Align center inline elements */
  font: 0/0 a;
  /* Hide the characters like spaces */ }

.brand-image-container {
  margin-bottom: 10px; }

.centerer {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%; }

.img-container img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  max-height: 100%;
  /* <-- Set maximum height to 100% of its parent */
  max-width: 100%;
  /* <-- Set maximum width to 100% of its parent */ }

.footer {
  padding: 15px 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.4;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #345; }

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  background-image: none;
  cursor: pointer; }

.btn-medium {
  margin: 10px 15px;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 1.33333333;
  text-shadow: none; }

.btn-true, .btn-false {
  padding: 5px 20px;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: 1px solid #336699;
  background-color: #337799; }

a {
  text-decoration: none; }

.go-down-section {
  margin-top: -1000px;
  transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out; }

.go-right-section {
  margin-left: -100%;
  transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out; }

.go-away {
  top: 0;
  position: absolute; }

@media (min-width: 640px) {
  .wrapper {
    width: 400px; } }
/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .wrapper {
    width: 400px; }

  .footer {
    font-size: 21px; } }
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#true1').click( function(){
    $('.section-one').addClass('go-down-section');
  });
  $('#false2').click( function(){
    $('.section-two').addClass('go-right-section');
    $('.section-three').addClass('go-away');
  });

});
```

**UPDATE:**

Here is a [codepen page with full code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qdqZrp)

Comment: @DarrenSweeney I forgot to add all code before I submitted the question. check CSS, JS code and updated section.

Answer (score 1):

> I have checked the FullPageJs JS libraries such as, **but I want to do
>   it without any library.**

You can go for it if you want to learn or do it as an exercise.

**If you really want to have a good end product**, tested by thousands, I would strongly suggest you to go for a library. Why? Well, libraries don't become big and popular just because people is lazy to code 200 lines. 
Here are some reasons:

- Highly tested in different devices and browsers by thousands of persons (Windows Phone, Adroid, iOS, touch screen computers, Opera, Safari...)
- Compatibility with touch devices.
- Compatibility with kinetic scrolling (Apple laptops, magic mouse...).
- Compatibility with old browsers (IE 8, Opera 12...).
- Good performance for modern browsers and touch devices (css3).
- Recalculate of sections and slides when resizing the viewport.
- Returning anchors in the URL.
- Responsive mode.
- Accessibility features (keyboard, scroll bar, browser history).
- Use of callbacks to fire actions.
- Plenty of methods and options.

And you get all of that for just 7Kb gzipped if you use fullPage.js.